# Running into spool error in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I´m trying to run the following query. The size is probably on the limit of the database, however similar sized tables were working.

I know there is a way to partition the query using HASHAMP, HASHBUCKET, HASHROW functions but i have no idea how to do this.

The query is simple, i´m just checking if the main_acct_product_id variable is on b table.

Some info about the tables inside the query:

```
sel count(*) from graph_total_3
678.336.354

top 5 of graph_total_3
id_phone    destino WEIGHT  DIR access_method_id    access_destino  operador    producto    operador_destino
2615071884  2615628271  0,42800 0,417000    T2615071884 T2615628271 A   aa  II
1150421872  1159393065  343,200 0,424000    T1150421872 T1159393065 B   bb  LI
2914076292  2914735291  0,16500 1,003,000   T2914076292 T2914735291 C   ar  OJ
2914735291  2914076292  0,16500 -0,003000   T2914735291 T2914076292 A   tm  JA
2804535124  2804454795  0,39600 1,000,000   T2804535124 T2804454795 B   ma  UE

primary key(id_phone, destino);

sel count(*) from producto
26.473.287

top 5 of producto
    Access_Method_Id    Main_Acct_Product_Id
    T2974002818         PR_PPAL_AHORRO  
    T3875943432         PR_PPAL_ACTIVA  
    T2616294339         PR_PPAL_ACTIVA  
    T3516468805         PR_PPAL_ACTIVA  
    T2616818855         PR_PPAL_ACTIVA  

primary key(Access_Method_Id);
```

**SHOW TABLE**

```
show table producto

CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE MARBEL.producto ,NO FALLBACK ,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     LOG
     (
      Access_Method_Id VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      Main_Acct_Product_Id CHAR(16) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC)
PRIMARY INDEX ( Access_Method_Id )
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

show table graph_total_3

CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE MARBEL.graph_total_3 ,NO FALLBACK ,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     LOG
     (
      id_phone VARCHAR(21) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      destino VARCHAR(21) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      WEIGHT DECIMAL(10,5),
      DIR DECIMAL(7,6),
      access_method_id VARCHAR(22) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      access_destino VARCHAR(22) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      operador VARCHAR(8) CHARACTER SET UNICODE NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      producto VARCHAR(16) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      operador_destino VARCHAR(8) CHARACTER SET UNICODE NOT CASESPECIFIC)
PRIMARY INDEX ( id_phone ,destino )
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

**QUERY**

```
create multiset volatile table graph_total_final as
(
select  a.* ,  coalesce(b.main_acct_product_id,'NO MOV') as producto_destino
from graph_total_3 a
left join producto b on a.access_destino=b.access_method_id
)
with data primary index (id_phone, destino)
on commit preserve rows;
```

**Explain**

```
     This query is optimized using type 1 profile bootstrap, profileid -/. 
      1) First, we create the table header. 
      2) Next, we do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from MARBEL.a by way of an
         all-rows scan with no residual conditions into Spool 2 (all_amps),
         which is redistributed by the hash code of (
         MARBEL.a.access_destino) to all AMPs.  Then we do a SORT to order
         Spool 2 by row hash.  The result spool file will not be cached in
         memory.  The size of Spool 2 is estimated with high confidence to
         be 678,343,248 rows (55,624,146,336 bytes).  The estimated time
         for this step is 2 minutes and 41 seconds. 
      3) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from Spool 2 (Last Use) by way of a
         RowHash match scan, which is joined to MARBEL.b by way of a
         RowHash match scan.  Spool 2 and MARBEL.b are left outer joined
         using a merge join, with condition(s) used for non-matching on
         left table ("NOT (access_destino IS NULL)"), with a join condition
         of ("access_destino = MARBEL.b.Access_Method_Id").  The result
         goes into Spool 1 (all_amps), which is redistributed by the hash
         code of (MARBEL.a.id_phone, MARBEL.a.destino) to all AMPs.  Then
         we do a SORT to order Spool 1 by row hash.  The result spool file
         will not be cached in memory.  The size of Spool 1 is estimated
         with index join confidence to be 25,085,452,093 rows (
         2,232,605,236,277 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 1
         hour and 45 minutes. 
      4) We do an all-AMPs MERGE into MARBEL.graph_total_final from Spool 1
         (Last Use). 
      5) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
         in processing the request.
      -> No rows are returned to the user as the result of statement 1.
```

**EXPLAIN 2**

After running:

```
DIAGNOSTIC HELPSTATS ON FOR SESSION;
EXPLAIN
create multiset volatile table graph_total_final as
(
select  a.* ,  coalesce(b.main_acct_product_id,'NO MOVISTAR') as producto_destino
from graph_total_3 a
left join producto b on a.access_destino=b.access_method_id
)
with data primary index (id_phone, destino, access_destino)
on commit preserve rows;

  EXPLAIN
create multiset volatile table graph_total_final as
(
select  a.* ,  coalesce(b.main_acct_product_id,'NO MOVISTAR') as producto_destino
from graph_total_3 a
left join producto b on a.access_destino=b.access_method_id
)
with data primary index (id_phone, destino, access_destino)
on commit preserve rows;

 This query is optimized using type 1 profile bootstrap, profileid -/. 
  1) First, we create the table header. 
  2) Next, we do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from MARBEL.a by way of an
     all-rows scan with no residual conditions into Spool 2 (all_amps),
     which is redistributed by the hash code of (
     MARBEL.a.access_destino) to all AMPs.  Then we do a SORT to order
     Spool 2 by row hash.  The result spool file will not be cached in
     memory.  The size of Spool 2 is estimated with high confidence to
     be 678,343,248 rows (55,624,146,336 bytes).  The estimated time
     for this step is 2 minutes and 41 seconds. 
  3) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from Spool 2 (Last Use) by way of a
     RowHash match scan, which is joined to MARBEL.b by way of a
     RowHash match scan.  Spool 2 and MARBEL.b are left outer joined
     using a merge join, with condition(s) used for non-matching on
     left table ("NOT (access_destino IS NULL)"), with a join condition
     of ("access_destino = MARBEL.b.Access_Method_Id").  The result
     goes into Spool 1 (all_amps), which is redistributed by the hash
     code of (MARBEL.a.id_phone, MARBEL.a.destino,
     MARBEL.a.access_destino) to all AMPs.  Then we do a SORT to order
     Spool 1 by row hash.  The result spool file will not be cached in
     memory.  The size of Spool 1 is estimated with index join
     confidence to be 25,085,452,093 rows (2,232,605,236,277 bytes). 
     The estimated time for this step is 1 hour and 45 minutes. 
  4) We do an all-AMPs MERGE into MARBEL.graph_total_final from Spool 1
     (Last Use). 
  5) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
     in processing the request.
  -> No rows are returned to the user as the result of statement 1. 
     BEGIN RECOMMENDED STATS ->
  6) "COLLECT STATISTICS MARBEL.producto COLUMN ACCESS_METHOD_ID". 
     (HighConf)
  7) "COLLECT STATISTICS MARBEL.graph_total_3 COLUMN ACCESS_DESTINO". 
     (HighConf)
     <- END RECOMMENDED STATS
```

Comment: can you confirm that you have ran `COLLECT STATISTICS MARBEL.producto COLUMN ACCESS_METHOD_ID` and `COLLECT STATISTICS MARBEL.graph_total_3 COLUMN ACCESS_DESTINO` statements successfully.

Comment: Sure, I have! It provides the same explain as it´s in: **EXPLAIN 2**

Comment: I see, can you post `show table <table-name>` output for both the tables.

Comment: Do you know how this would work using  `HASHAMP, HASHBUCKET, HASHROW`functions

Comment: How much spool space does your user have? How much spool space are you consuming with each of the VOLATILE tables you created before the third one spools out? What is the distribution of your spool utilization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those tables are Volatile Tables, which means you created them within your current session and you have control over their definition.

When you change the Primary Index of **MARBEL.graph_total_3** to **access_destino** you'll get a direct AMP-local join without any preparation (and you don't need to collect stats as this will not change the plan, just the estimated numbers are closer to reality).

Due to the new PI the table might be skewed, but when you look at Exolain you'll see that otherwise the spool will have a PI on **access_destino**.

And if **MARBEL.producto.Access_Method_Id** is actually unique you should define the PI a unique, too. This will also improve estimates.

Comment: So the advise is to change the MARBEL.graph_total_3 PI to PI i will join the other table. The Access_Method_Id field is unique. Thx!

Comment: Yes, the fastest possible join in Teradata is always based on matching Primary Indexes (and matching partitioning).

Comment: @dnoeth what do you mean with matching partitioning?

Comment: A table might be partitioned additionally to a Primary Index, e.g. *PRIMARY INDEX(colA) PARTITION BY RANGE_N(datecol BETWEEN DATE '2010-01-01' AND DATE '2014-12-31' EACH INTERVAL '1' DAY)*. To get a local join you need the same PI and the same partiton definition in both tables and join on both *colA* and *datecol*

Answer (score 2):

Two things strike odd to me straight off the bat.

I would suggest avoid using `select a.*,...` unless you really need to bring all columns from the A-table. This will reduce the amount of data that needs to be held in spool.

The second thing which looks suspecious is this sentence in #3 `The size of Spool 1 is estimated with index join confidence to be 25,085,452,093 rows` Are you sure the B-table is unique by `access_method_id` column - if not you could be inadvertently creating a cartesian product. (25billion rows! - really!).

Also, tell us about the demographics of your A & B table (i.e., primary indexes, whether the tables are partitioned or not).

**Update (after seeing additional information)**
The only other thing I can think of ( especially if your Teradata environment is not particularly beefy with lots of disk space) is to make sure your data is as compressed as possible. This will save space (even when data is stored in spool space) and reduce the amount of spool space required.

Following are the candidates for compression in the B-table.

```
Main_Acct_Product_Id CHAR(16) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC COMPRESS ('PR_PPAL_AHORRO', 'PR_PPAL_ACTIVA', <continue with list for about the 200 most frequently occuring main ac product ids>).
```

By doing this, without increasing the cpu time, you can compress each 16byte string down to a few bits.

Similarly do the same for the following columns in the A-table.

```
      operador VARCHAR(8) CHARACTER SET UNICODE NOT CASESPECIFIC compress('A','B', 'C', <other more frequently occuring operdor ids>),
      producto VARCHAR(16) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC compress('aa','bb', 'ar', <other more frequently occuring producto ids>),
      operador_destino VARCHAR(8) CHARACTER SET UNICODE NOT CASESPECIFIC compress('II','LI', 'OJ', <other more frequently occuring operador_destion ids>)
```

consider storing id_phone  & destino as either int or bigint(if int is not big enough). Bigint takes up 8bytes where as storing in varchar you are expending upto 10-12bytes. When you have 100's millions of rows every byte saved helps. You can compress WEIGHT  DIR columns too - ex: if `0.0000` is the most frequently occuring weight/dir then you can specify compress(0.0000) and gain space. All the `compress` statements must be specified at table creation time.

access method_id and access_destino appears to be just id_phone with 'T' prefixed see if you can strip of the first alphabet and store them as integers. All of this should yield considerable space saving and hopefully could reduce the amt. of spool space needed to execute your query.

Lastly, I'm not aware of partitioning the query (i've partitioned tables but not queries) by hashamp/bucket/row - Teradata is supposed to execute all queries in  parallel anyway.

Comment: @MartínBel, in that case the problem could be with the A table. Note from the explain output that A-table is being re-distributed by `access_destino`. Do you know if `statistics` are collected on this column? If not collect them and run the explain again.

Comment: `COLLECT STATISTICS  COLUMN (access_destino) ON graph_total_3;` hopefully you have access rights to collect the stats if not see your DBA.

Comment: Can you post output of `diagnostic helpstats on for session;
explain
create multiset volatile table graph_total_final as
(
select  a.* ,  coalesce(b.main_acct_product_id,'NO MOV') as producto_destino
from graph_total_3 a
left join producto b on a.access_destino=b.access_method_id
)
with data primary index (id_phone, destino)
on commit preserve rows;`